# How to keep matched groups of pattern recursion in regex?

Tags: regex, pcre

I have this problem where i'm trying to validate an input using regex. the input should correspond to a specific programmation-like norm, that consist on function, variables (2 types) and strings.

Here's some examples :

```
&foo
$foo(&bar)
$foo(&bar+$baz)
$foo($bar "baz" qux+$quux(&corge "grault") &garply)
```

Types that exists:

- $bar - variable
- &foo - variable (second type)
- "baz" - string
- qux - *litteral* string
- $quux(...) - function

The main problem here is that I've written a regex, with recusion of course. But, I need to validate the fact that, in the final match itself or within its recursions, there is at least **one** variable of the second type - which isn't actually the case. Obviously, my regex should fullmatch the input.

So here's my regex (it uses PCRE2), followed by its explanation, and a suit of tests for you to try it:

#### Regex

```
(?:\$\w+(?:\((?<arg>(?R)|(?:\"[^\"]*\")|(?:[^\$\"\&\s\(\)][^\s\(\)]*))(?:(?:\+| )(?&arg))*\))?)|(?<var>\&\w+)
```

#### Explanations

```
(?:                           # function or variable and its arguments
  \$\w+                         # function or variable prefix + name (ex: $test)
  (?:                           # arguments if it's a function
    \(                            # opening parenthesis
    (?<arg>                       # first argument
      (?R)                          # function or variable
      |
      (?:\"[^\"]*\")                # string
      |
      (?:[^\$\"\&\s\(\)][^\s\(\)]*) # string literal
    )
    (?:                           # other arguments if any
      (?:\+| )                      # separator
      (?&arg)                       # argument
    )*
    \)                            # closing parenthesis
  )?
)
|
(?<var>\&\w+)                 # variable prefix + name (ex: &test)
```

#### Human-readable translation

```
(                         # function or variable and its arguments
  \$\w+                     # function or variable prefix + name (ex: $test)
  MAYBE (                   # arguments if it's a function
    \(                        # opening parenthesis
    GROUP <arg> (             # first argument
      RECURSIVE                 # function or variable
      OR
      \"[^\"]*\"                # string
      OR
      [^\$\"\&\s\(\)][^\s\(\)]* # string literal
    )
    MAYBE MULTIPLE (          # other arguments if any
      \+ OR SPACE               # separator
      GROUP arg                 # argument
    )
    \)                        # closing parenthesis
  )
)
OR
GROUP <var> (\&\w+)       # variable prefix + name (ex: &test)
```

The goal is to transform it the verify that the group `var` is present at least once, within the regex or its recursions.

**The best solution would be that `(?R)` kept the group matched within recursion and pass them to his parent pattern, I would be able to check if the group `var` matched at least once with `(?(var)(*ACCEPT)|(*FAIL))`.**

**Here's a simplified version of what I'm thinking about: `(?:\w(?R)|(\d))(?(1)(*ACCEPT)|(*FAIL))`. This regex only matches 1 digit, but with "recursion matches-keeping", it whould match any chain of letters followed by a digit.**

**However, it seems that it's not possible at all. I didn't found a flag nor a token for this.**

#### Test/Examples

```
$test($test(test &var1 $var2) $test(jean) jean) # should full-match
$test($test(test $var1 $var2) $test(foo) bar)   # should not full-match
$test("&test")                                  # should not full-match
$test("foo&test")                               # should not full-match
$test("&test" &test)                            # should full-match
&test                                           # should full-match
$test(" &test")                                 # should not full-match
$test                                           # should not full-match
&test(foo)                                      # should not full-match
&test(&foo $bar())                              # should not full-match
$test((&test))                                  # should not full-match
$foo(bar(&baz))                                 # should not full match
$test(&test  &test)                             # should not full match
$test( &test)                                   # should not full match
$test(&test )                                   # should not full match
```

[Here's a link to my regex101 tests for you to try and test it.](https://regex101.com/r/OIfYcE/4)

Comment: It's not fool proof, but perhaps with a lookahead `^(?:&\w+|\$\w+(?=.*\([^()"\n]*(?:"[^"\n]*"[^()"\n]*)*&\w[^()]*\))(\((?>[^()]++|(?1))*\)))$` https://regex101.com/r/pLvVBa/1

Comment: Thanks, that's a big step @Thefourthbird ! However, it also matches `$test((&test))`, which should not be the case.

Comment: Why should that not match?

Comment: Because there's nothing as parenthesis in this syntax, except for functions. Therefore, `(test)` is treated as a string litteral. Since the input does not contain a variable of the second type, the pattern must not match @Thefourthbird

Comment: You might rule out those occurrences with a negative lookahead https://regex101.com/r/bVILL4/1

Comment: My bad, I guess I didn't provided enought test cases. This pattern matches `$foo(bar(&baz))`, which shouldn't be the case, since `bar(&baz)` isn't a function but a string litteral. Therefore, there aren't any variable of the second type and the pattern shouldn't match.
I'm now going to update my question to add more test cases. Thanks for your help @Thefourthbird !

Comment: What is the logic for this second type variable? This whole line should match `$test("&test" &test)` but this should not `$test(&test )` Why is that? Should this match? `$test(&test)`

Comment: This isn't about the second variable type, but about functions. Functions doesn't allow multiple spaces between arguments, and doesn't allow useless spaces. Only variables, strings, and concatenations (via `+`) of both. `$test(&test)` is valid since it's a function that contains one argument : a variable. @Thefourthbird

Comment: May be much ugly but [try this](https://regex101.com/r/M3duIT/1)

Comment: @klee: Very good job and very clever pattern, you should post it as an answer. If you do it, please explain your trick in details.